# Matrix Transpose python 4x3 to 3x4 python

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

**Hi guys, so I have a problem. Can you please help me with it, I do not understand why my code is incorrect.
I have a matrix:

```
a = [
    [33,15,14],
    [3,55,21],
    [0,17,12],
    [7,0,15]
]
and need to transpose it to:
Transpose = [
    [33,3,0,7],
    [15,55,17,0],
    [14,21,12,15]
]
T = [
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0]
]
print(T)
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        T[i][j] = a[j][i]
```

Why after this code do I get an error of index being out of range?
Wouldn't it iterate like:

```
a[0][0] = a[0][0]
a[0][1] = a[1][0]
a[0][2] = a[2][0]
```

and etc.**

Comment: Use: `T[j][i] = a[i][j]`. More generally, you need to learn howto debug samll programs: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `aT = list(map(list, zip(*a)))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: HI), Well I need to make a tranpose of matrix a. So i thought that iterating elements as i showed above will work however, it doesn't and i do not understand why.

Answer (score -1):

`len(a)` gives the number of objects in the array

however you never consider the fact that an array has 0 as the first position.

try `len(a)-1` and `len(a[0])-1` it should work.

Comment: range(4) only goes 0,1,2,3  .. the 4 is not provided.